# How can one generalize the Gauss map to higher dimensions? More specifically, bi-dimensional manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

It's easy to define the unitary tangent fields of a $2$-dimensional surface $S: I \times J \to \mathbb{R}^4$, but since I don't have the cross product anymore, an unitary normal field is harder to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to generalize the Gauss map is to convince yourself that in the classical setting for of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a choice of unit normal field is equivalent to a choice of orientation, because the tangent planes determine the normal direction at each point (in the presence of a metric). If you drop the orientation, then you only have the family of tangent planes, that you can view as a mapping from your surface into the space of $2$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words,  modulo the orientation, the Gauss map is determined by either tangent planes or normal lines.

Formally speaking, the range of the Gauss map (dropping the orientation) is the [Grassmanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $\mathbf{Gr}(1, 3) \cong \mathbf{Gr}(2, 3) \cong \mathbb{P}^2$, that the projective plane, which locally looks like the $2$-sphere.

In your case (2-surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$), knowing locally an orthogonal frame is  sufficient to think of this frame as a mapping from the surface into the Grassmanian $\mathbf{Gr}(2, 4)$.